# Subtitles in Video Player

Tags: release-juno, video-player

Subtitles still don't appear to work in the video player, I have read the other two questions on this site, but neither have a fix.

I am using an external srt subtitle file that works on windows using VLC.

Developers: Please take a look at the question here for more details (and a bounty) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957527/cluttergst-only-shows-external-subtitles-if-same-filename-as-video-file

Comment: Have you tried it with Linux on VLC?

Comment: I have not, but what would it prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File a bug report at the relevant Github repo elementary/videos.

Alternatively there is an issue already open [Audience doesn't show subtitles](https://github.com/elementary/videos/issues/32) here. Try renaming the subtitles to match the video file exactly.

Comment: This, renaming the subtitles to match the video file exactly works.